quantum phase estimation overperiod value estimation
Basacally, QPE allows to find eigenvalue within a period  $[0$ to $2\pi)$. Is there an extention that allows to calculate eigenvalue out of these limits, e.g. greater or equal to $2 \pi$?

QPE allows you to find eigenvalues of the form $e^{i \phi}$. Hence, if you find $\phi \in [0, 2\pi )$, then $\phi + 2\pi$ will correspond to the very same eigenvalue.

yeah, exactly. I mean, is there any hint to obviously separate $\phi$ and $2\pi + \phi$?

What do you mean by "separate"? The algorithm itself spits out an approximation of $\lambda$ were the eigenvalue would be $e^{2\pi i \lambda}$ and $\lambda$ is given in binary encoding in the respective qubit register. This is due to how the QFT works.

That what my last comment about. QPE can compute $\phi$. How to compute $2\pi + \phi$, $4\pi + \phi$, $6\pi + \phi$,....? With clear understanding how many full $2\pi$ periods was involved.

If you insist on getting $2\pi + \phi$ you probably have to use QPE to get $\phi$ and then add $2\pi$ manually. I know this is not what you are asking for, but I think there is no other way due to the non-injective mapping of the exponential (when it comes to the phase) (see: Complex Logarithm ). In the end, it does not matter because the eigenvalue itself is always the same.
